# How to avoid hardcoded picklist values in Azure pipeline yaml?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Can azure devops pipeline yaml drive picklist values from a file so to avoid hardcoded values in yaml ?  Even better allow an api call to dynamically populate a list

Naturally we can roll our own synthesis of pipeline yaml code short of that would be nice if it allowed an include snippets file ability ... one means would be to run a pipeline to generate a pipeline to get run

azure pipeline bad technique today requires a hardcode

```
        parameters:
          - name: some_parm
            type: string
            default: fav_value
            values:
              - val01
              - val02
              - val03
```

what is needed ... populate list dynamically or at a minimum from a file

```
        parameters:
          - name: some_parm
            type: string
            default: fav_value
            values:
              ${{ some_file_or_api_lookup }}
```

Possibly this yaml preprocessor could work  https://github.com/birchb1024/goyamp  ... dunno yet

***UPDATE***  20220906  so far no solution found suggestions welcome

Comment: Well, this comment is not answer to your original question but if you want to shorten your .yaml a little use brackets[]

values: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8].

I will follow this question because I have also recently wondered if it is possible to evaluate somehow allowed values.

Comment: But I highly doubt that it is possible, because parameters should be evaluated before the pipeline runs. If I want to run any pipeline from AzureDevOps website I have 'selection window' which allows me to choose one of these 1-to-8 numbers before running pipeline.

Comment: Did you ever find anything which worked for this?